# MSXMLl 6.0 XmlDOMNodeList fails when is invoked GetEnumerator

Tags: c#, .net, com, marshalling, msxml

Our project uses `MSXML 6.0` com object for working with `XML` through `ComImport` attribute. Below com Class which provides access to existing `MSXML COM`(I left only SelectNodes for clarify problem ).

```
[ComImport]
[ComSourceInterfaces("MSXML2.XMLDOMDocumentEvents")]
[TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FCanCreate)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("88d96a06-f192-11d4-a65f-0040963251e5")]
public class FreeThreadedDOMDocumentClass : IXMLDOMDocument2
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x1d)]
    public extern object SelectNodes([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string queryString);

}

[ComImport, Guid("2933BF95-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60"), TypeLibType((short)0x10c0)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IXMLDOMDocument2
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x1d)]
    object SelectNodes([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string queryString);
}

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1710:IdentifiersShouldHaveCorrectSuffix"), ComImport]
[Guid("2933BF82-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60")]
[TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FDispatchable)]//(short) 0x10c0
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IXMLDOMNodeList: IEnumerable
{

    [DispId(0)]
    IXMLDOMNode this[int index]
    {
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
      [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0)]
      get;
    }


    [DispId(0x4a)]
    int Count
    {
      [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x4a)]
      get;
    }
}
```

And We have problem with some parts of code. Example :

```
string xmlText = "<Item> <Element></Element></Item>";
IXMLDOMDocument2 domDocument = new FreeThreadedDOMDocumentClass();
domDocument.LoadXml(xmlText);
string xPath = "//Item";
IXMLDOMNodeList resultQuery = domDocument.SelectNodes(xPath) as IXMLDOMNodeList;
resultQuery.GetEnumerator()
```

Obtained object `resultQuery`  as result of execution of `SelectNodes` has problem with GetEnumerator depending on some outside factors:

1. In windows 7 or more early systems (system without support of WinRT technology)

   - obtained object `resultQuery` has type `System.__ComObject`
   - resultQuery.GetEnumerator()  executes without any problem and provide working Enumerator
2. In windows 8 or more later systems (system with support of WinRT technology)

   - obtained object `resultQuery` has type `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlNodeList`. This is WinRt type.
   - resultQuery.GetEnumerator() throws exception:`System.ArgumentException: The object's type must not be a Windows Runtime type`.  I figured out that source of exception is `Marshal.GetComObjectData`. It means that our Marshalling process fails
3. In windows 8 or more later systems with version of imported com `MSXML 3.0` :

   - obtained object `resultQuery` has type `System.__ComObject`
   - resultQuery.GetEnumerator()  executes without any problem and provide working Enumerator

At this moment I found three workarounds  for point 2 (using msxml on windows with WinRT) but not the solutions for us (It can be helpful for developers with the same issue):

1. Do not use foreach and GetEnumerator. it's clear :)
2. Create custom marshalling for `SelectNodes` with using [ICustomMarshaler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.icustommarshaler(v=vs.110).aspx) which will  create wrapper over WinRT type and provide custom GetEnumerator through `for`.
3. Change version of msxml from 6 to 3.

I need help to find  source of problem in point 2 and understand how to fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deep investigation i have found solution:

1) I generated interop C# dll for msxml6 com  with [TLBimp.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(v=vs.110).aspx)

2) Opened generated dll with decompiler

3) Found generated interface `IXMLDOMNodeList`.
 It has next implementation:

```
[Guid("2933BF82-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60"), TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FDual | TypeLibTypeFlags.FNonExtensible | TypeLibTypeFlags.FDispatchable)]
[ComImport]
public interface IXMLDOMNodeList : IEnumerable
{
    // Token: 0x1700012B RID: 299
    [DispId(0)]
    IXMLDOMNode this[[In] int index]
    {
        [DispId(0)]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
        get;
    }

    // Token: 0x1700012C RID: 300
    // (get) Token: 0x060003D5 RID: 981
    [DispId(74)]
    int length
    {
        [DispId(74)]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        get;
    }

    // Token: 0x060003D6 RID: 982
    [DispId(76)]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
    IXMLDOMNode nextNode();

    // Token: 0x060003D7 RID: 983
    [DispId(77)]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    void reset();

    // Token: 0x060003D8 RID: 984
    [TypeLibFunc(TypeLibFuncFlags.FRestricted | TypeLibFuncFlags.FHidden), DispId(-4)]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(EnumeratorToEnumVariantMarshaler))]
    IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}
```

How can we see generated interface has some additioanl methods : `nextNode`  `reset` and overrided 'GetEnumerator'

I addes missed methods to my implementation of `IXMLDOMNodeList` and this fixed all problem with `GetEnumerator` in systems with WinRT.

Comment: Artsiom thanks for turning this up. I am trying to do the exact same thing, using MSXML 6 (it's not feasible for me to back off to MSXML 3). I too am trying to iterate through a set of retrieved nodes. Your answer is not crystal clear, I hope I don't have to go deconstruct DLLs, add to IXMLDOMNodeList. That seems like way way deeper than hoped for, to avoid a problem in a current MSXML version. Have you discovered any other approaches to coding this? I am using VBScript in .NET framework. Thank you.